# The equation $(1+x)^2\frac{dy}{dx}-xy=x^2y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am very grateful for all your comments and answers to my previous question concerning ODEs ( [The equation $(x-2xy-y^2)\frac{dy}{dx}+y^2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79207/the-equation-x-2xy-y2-fracdydxy2-0) ). Now I am struggling with this one

$$(1+x)^2\frac{dy}{dx}-xy=x^2y^2.$$

It seems not to be hard but nevertheless all the tricks I know fail in this case.

Best regards,
D.

Comment: Did you check [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bx%29%5E2+y%27%28x%29+-+x*y%28x%29%3Dx%5E2+y%28x%29%5E2) ? It suggests it is solvable in special functions.

Comment: Do you want to find an explicit solution to this? It is [non-elementary](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bx%29^2+y%27+%3D+%28xy%29^2+%2B+xy).

Comment: This is a [Bernoulli equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation).

Comment: An implicit solution would be fine as well. @Sasha what kind of special functions do you mean?

Comment: @DariaMorys It was [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) $Ei(x)$.

Comment: @process91, is that clear this way leads to the solution? In my taste it makes this equation even more complicated.

Comment: @DariaMorys You are correct, that is more complicated.

Comment: If you try the usual route for solving Bernoulli equations, you'll have to tangle with an integral that's not expressible elementarily. That's where $\mathrm{Ei}$ comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1**.
Let $y(x) = \frac{1}{w(x)}$. Then $y^\prime(x) = -\frac{1}{w(x)^2}\cdot w^\prime(x)$, so the differential equation becomes $ \frac{(1+x)^2 w^\prime(x) + x w(x) + x^2}{w(x)^2} = 0$, that is $ w^\prime(x) + \frac{x}{(1+x)^2} w(x) + \frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2}=0$.

**Step 2**. Integrating factor, let $w(x) = f(x) g(x)$, and we will seek $f(x)$ so as to get rid of the term $x w(x)$. Substituting, $f^\prime(x) g(x) + f(x) g^\prime(x) + \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}f(x) g(x) + \frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2} = 0$. Choosing $f(x)$ such that $f^\prime(x) + \frac{x}{(1+x)^2} f(x) = 0$, the equation becomes $ g^\prime(x) = -\frac{1}{f(x)} \frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2}$, which is readily solvable for a known $f(x)$.

**Step 3**. Solve the auxiliary equation $f^\prime(x) = -\frac{x}{(1+x)^2} f(x)$. For this, rewrite it as $\left( \log( f(x) )\right)^\prime = - \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$, and integrate both sides, giving $\log(f(x)) = \int \frac{x}{(1+x)^2} \mathrm{d} x + C = \log(1+x) - \frac{x}{1+x} + \log f_0$. That is $f(x) = f_0 (1+x) \exp\left( - \frac{x}{1+x} \right)$.

**Step 4**. Solve the ODE for $g(x)$ by direct integration:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
   g(x) &=& -\int \frac{1}{f(x)} \frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2} \mathrm{d} x + C = - \int \frac{1}{f_0} \exp\left( \frac{x}{1+x} \right) \frac{x^2}{(1+x)^3} \mathrm{d} x + C \\ 
  &\stackrel{x=-\frac{t+1}{t}}{=}& \frac{\mathrm{e}}{f_0} \int  \mathrm{e}^{t} \frac{t^2+2 t + 1}{t} \mathrm{d} t + C = \frac{\mathrm{e}}{f_0} \mathrm{e}^t (1+t) + \frac{\mathrm{e}}{f_0} \int \frac{\mathrm{e}^t}{t} \mathrm{d} t + C
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The remaining integral is not elementary, let's denote it by $F(t) = \int \mathrm{e}^t \frac{\mathrm{d} t}{t}$.

**Step 5**. Find $y(x) = \frac{1}{w(x)} = \frac{1}{f(x) g(x)}$.
$$
   y(x) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{1+x}}}{(1+x)\left( \exp\left(\frac{x}{1+x} \right) \frac{x}{1+x} + F\left(-\frac{1}{1+x}\right) + C\right)} = \frac{1}{x + (1+x) \exp\left( - \frac{x}{1+x} \right) \left( F\left( -\frac{1}{1+x} \right) + C \right) }
$$

**Step 6**. *Check your equation*. 
Are you sure the original equation is correct ? Should you have $(1+x^2) y^\prime(x)$, instead of $(1+x)^2 y^\prime(x)$, the solution would come out elementary.

Comment: Thank you. $(1+x)^2$ is the example I was interested in.